# Can I override func mouseDown Without Subclassing?

Tags: swift, macos, subclass, mousedown

Can I override func mouseDown only for a specific instance of NSView without subclassing?

I can do something like this using lambda in Java (see below), but can I do something like this using closure in Swift?

```
something.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
    @Override public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
        ...
    }

    @Override public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        ...
    }
});
```

Answer (score -3):

You can write this way.  Also works.

```
extension NSView {

override open func mouseDown(with event: NSEvent) {

}

}
```

Comment: Nope; this is undefined behavior. You're also extending _every_ `NSView` in the program -- including those you did not create -- not just a particular instance.

Comment: This directly answer his question. It provides one possiblity we may need some day.

Comment: Is mouseDown not considered as existing functionality? "Extensions can add new functionality to a type, but they cannot override existing functionality." https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Extensions.html

Comment: It overrides mouseDown for all views though. I need different behavior for each instance.